macOS text editing keyboard Shortcuts not working in Blender
Using a MacBook keyboard, I have significant problems with shortcuts that I don't encounter in any other software. Namely, it is unable to use the frequently used hotkeys for text editing across Blender, such as:
Option+Backspace to delete the word to the left of the cursor,
Cmd+Backspace to delete the whole string to the left of the cursor
I found the Keymap settings under Preferences > Keymap > Text (Global), where I can redefine the shortcut for deleting the previous word. However, this change only applies to the Text Editor and not globally across Blender, meaning it doesn't affect other sections like the Outliner. Additionally, there is no option in the Text (Global) settings to assign a hotkey for deleting the entire string.
I just want Blender to work normally with text, allowing me to delete the preceding word and the entire string using the default Mac shortcuts throughout the application, is it feasible.

